# Oauth 2.0: how pass user information to protected resources (API Rest)

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0

I'm implementing a native app for Android that uses Oauth2 for authorization.
I was able to implement the authorization code flow to obtain the access_token from the authorization server, so my app can use this token to access resources (Rest api) deployed in resource server.
But the resource need some user informations (email, roles, etc..) to make a decision for the response to return to the app.
My question is: how pass the user informations to the rest api ?

I inform you that my resources are protected by a j2ee filter that validates the tokens through interaction with authorization server.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your own design, you can design it as Google’s, for example:

https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/fileId/comments/commentId

or twitter's, for example:

http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/home_timeline.json?since_id=12345&max_id=54321

Comment: Thanks Owen. My doubt is how retrieve the user informations, stored in the authorization server and managed by the j2ee filter during authentication.

Comment: Once the resource service get your api request with access token, it will send it to Oauth to validate it, and the oauth server will return result of validation to the resource server. The result contains user information like email, name and so on. Your app can not touch these user infos which are protected by Oauth.